# Getting error when trying to run the webpack-dev-server all of a sudden, unknown property of "fs"

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When trying to run Webpack Dev Server, I get a long error message: 47 errors and 10 warnings. I had no errors before, and then all of a sudden I do get errors. I have changed nothing in my webpack config.
Most of the error messages were about:

```
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

And how it `Failed to compile.`
The solutions it offered me inside the terminal were about the polyfills, like this one:

```
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
            - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
            - install 'crypto-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
            resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

And for many other packages as well. I installed all of them and added them to my webpack config file.

```js
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: require.resolve("util/"),
        path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
        https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
        os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
        vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        constants: require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
        assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
      },
    },
```

Still could not compile, I now have 9 errors and 10 warnings. All errors were about `fs`.

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchEventSource.js 7:11-24
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\My\Path\To\My\Project\node_modules\watchpack\lib'
```

but for two other errors, there were about `worker_threads` and `child_process`.

I tried to look up solutions online and found that I can add

```
    node: { fs: false },
```

But that didn't work. And if I comment out the previously installed resolve.fallback packages or not, I get the same error message:

```
    [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
     - configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
       object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
       -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! wp_book_theme@1.0.0 start: `webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js --open`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the wp_book_theme@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Now it can't even try to compile.
I am at my wit's end, and not sure what to do from here. Most solutions I found online were about `node: { fs:  false }`, which does not work for me.
I'd appreciated some help on this matter.

Here are also my full Webpack Config Files:
`webpack.common.js`

```js
    const path = require("path");
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: "./dev/script.js",
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            use: ["html-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(svg|png|jpg)$/i,
            use: {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                esModule: false,
                name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                outputPath: "assets/images",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```js
    const path = require("path");
    const common = require("./webpack.common.js");
    const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    
    module.exports = merge(common, {
      mode: "development",
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: "./dev/post.html",
        }),
      ],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          },
        ],
      },
      node: {
          fs: false
      },
      devServer: {
        inline: false,
        contentBase: "./dist",
      },
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
              // fs: false,
              // util: require.resolve("util/"),
              // path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
              // crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
              // buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
              // https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
              // http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
              // os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
              // vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
              // stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
              // constants: require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
              // assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
        },
      },
      output: {
        filename: "script.dev.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "./",
      },
    });
```

Here is the complete log of this run:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~prestart: wp_book_theme@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: wp_book_theme@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Art Files\Design\Eigene Projekte\WP Book Theme Dev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Wiktoria\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Programme\node-v12.18.0-win-x64;C:\Users\Wiktoria\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Wiktoria\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Wiktoria\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Wiktoria\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
9 verbose lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\Art Files\Design\Eigene Projekte\WP Book Theme Dev
10 silly lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle wp_book_theme@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: wp_book_theme@1.0.0 start: `webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid wp_book_theme@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Art Files\Design\Eigene Projekte\WP Book Theme Dev
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error wp_book_theme@1.0.0 start: `webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js --open`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the wp_book_theme@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `script.js`. I'm not sure where this piece of code came from, because I did not write it, but this suddenly appeared there and gave me headaches:

```
import { ContextExclusionPlugin } from "webpack";
```

It might have been autocomplete, so pay attention to this as well.